# How do redirect to the Sign Up Page in Accounts Entry

Tags: meteor, router, iron

When I open the /overview page it redirects me to the NotFound Template. The problem is, that I know that this site exists. What I want is, that this site redirect to the SignIn page instead of the SiteNotFound Page.

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('overview', {
    path :  '',
    controller :  OverviewController,

    // Only a signed in User can use CaptainKanban
    before:  AccountsEntry.signInRequired(this)
  });
});
```

I tried this

```
Router.configure({
    notFoundTemplate: 'entrySignIn'
});
```

this will redirect me to the signin Page when i go to /overview but also when i go to a page that really doesn't exist.

Oh and sorry for my bad english :( hope you understand what i mean.

Answer (score 0):

your router configuration for overview route is incorrect.

try this

```
Router.map(function () {
  this.route('overview', {
    path :  '/overview',
    controller :  OverviewController,

    // Only a signed in User can use CaptainKanban
    before:  AccountsEntry.signInRequired(this)
  });
});
```

and remove this line

```
notFoundTemplate: 'entrySignIn'
```

Comment: ok thanks. but that does not solved my problem. any further ideas?

Comment: I got it :)

Solution is:

    Router.map(function () {
      this.route('overview', {
        path :  '/overview',
        controller :  overviewController,
    
        onBeforeAction: function (pause) {
                if (!Meteor.user()) {
                // render the login template but keep the url in the browser the same
                 Router.go('entrySignIn');
                }
            }
      });
    });

"before:" is deprecated